# Why does my html page has a default width?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to change an website from fixed layout to a responsive layout but I am having problems setting up the html width. As you can see in the image below the width of html tag is 980px even if the page is empty, no css or js, just the html tags and doctype (the head and body are added automatically by browser):
[image: html width defaults to a value]

For testing I am using the Google Chrome Dev Emulator set up as Apple Iphone, I also tested on a phone and still the page looks too big for the screen.
Do you have any idea what to change to make my html tag width vanish?

Comment: Checked your emulator settings?

Comment: Maybe because the emulator uses `980px` as default width for iPhone? An HTML tag always has a default width – the width of the client window. (screen-width minus scrollbar-width…)

Comment: I am using Google Canary with default settings for iPhone 5, loading other mobile sites works well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's your Dev Emulator. According to the [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html) by Apple (under "Examples of Viewports on iOS"), the default size of the viewport of the iPhone is 980px. The Dev Emulator is then...emulating that page size for you. If you want to make it go away, just turn off the emulator or adjust any settings it may have.

Comment: yes, this is the answer, thanks! just adding the meta tag viewport solved my problem.